# How to get specific fields in the login form

Tags: users, forms

I'm trying to customize the login form. I added this to my template.php

```
function neptune_theme() {
  $items = array();
  $items['user_login'] = array(
    'render element' => 'form',
    'path' => drupal_get_path('theme', 'neptune') ,
    'template' => 'user-login',
    'preprocess functions' => array(
       'neptune_preprocess_user_login'
    ),
  );
  return $items;
}
```

and this is my user-login.tpl.php

```
<p><?php print render($intro_text); ?></p>
<div class="user-login">
  <?php print drupal_render_children($form) ?>
     <div class="links">
    <a href="/user/register">Create an Account</a> | <a href="/user/password">Forgot Password</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

I wanna know how to show the username, password and submit fields separately in the user-login.tpl.php file. I want to put the links for "Create an account" and "Forgot your password" before the Submit button.

I want to show something like

---

|Username                 |

---

---

|Password                 |

---

Create an Account | Forgot your password

---

|Submit|

---

Thank You. I hope it makes sense. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a user login template. In your theme file, put this function in and replace your_themename with the machine name of your theme.

```
function your_themename_theme() {
  $items = array();
  $items['user_login'] = array(
  'render element' => 'form',
  'path' => drupal_get_path('theme', 'your_themename') . '/templates',
  'template' => 'user-login',
  'preprocess functions' => array(
  'your_themename_preprocess_user_login'
  ),
 );
return $items;
}
```

Then, you can split the individual fields of the form up in a template file called `user-login.tpl.php` and rearrange them however you want.

```
<?php
    print drupal_render($form['name']);
    print drupal_render($form['pass']);
    print drupal_render($form['form_build_id']);
    print drupal_render($form['form_id']);
    print drupal_render($form['actions']);
?>
```

Source: [High Rock Media](http://highrockmedia.com/blog/customizing-user-login-page-drupal-7)